# Hammer.js behaviour of userSelect for nested HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, hammer.js

I use hammer.js for multitouch support. By default hammer.js suppresses text selection when handling touch events. This can be controlled via the "behaviour.userSelect" option. However, I do not fully understand how this works. What I need is, to prevent the text selection in some top level HTML element, while allowing it in one of its child elements.

Given the structure:

```
<div id="outer">
     Outer text
    <div id="inner" >
        Inner text
    </div>    
</div>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
// selection of "Outer text" should be impossible
$("#outer").hammer({behavior : { userSelect : "none", userDrag : "none"}}).on("hold", function(event) {
       console.log("hold-event")
});

// selection of "Inner text" should be possible
$("#inner").hammer({behavior : {userSelect : false}}).on("hold", function(event) {
    console.log("tap-event");
});
```

However this does not work - this code prevents text selection for **both** div-element. I have also played around with prevent_default but so far without success.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7tWDr/6/

What surprises me is, that the outer element effects the inner one. I would not expect this to happen with event bubbling being apparently the mechanism used by hammer.js. 
I have studied the hammer.js source code for quite some time but still haven't figured out how exactly hammer.js does the event handling so I basically have to questions:

1. How can I solve my initial problem?
2. How does Hammer.js process browser events and how are the events handled with regards to nested hierachies?

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards

Benjamin

Comment: {userSelect: "text"} will allow You to select text. Althought it looks like outer div is above inner doesnt matter what you will do (I've play with z-index css, hierarchy of code and deleting userSelect and nothing works.. ) I will tray to produce code in near future..

Comment: userSelect: "text" should have the same effect as userSelect : false. Meanwhile, we have worked around our problem by using touch-action css-attribute and generally handling things a bit different. This issue still remains puzzling to me.