# Any drawbacks of using Hammer.js on desktop browsers?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, hammer.js

I have started to use Hammer.js to implement drag functionality for mobile browsers. I have noticed that this functionality also works on desktop browsers (which is confirmed by this compatibility table https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Compatibility ).

Are there any drawbacks of using Hammer.js for desktop browsers as well?

As an example; let's say I want to implement a scrollbar (from scratch) where the "thumb" can be dragged. Instead of implementing this using onmousedown/up, onmousemove and set/release mousecapture I can simply use the dragstart, drag and dragend events of Hammer.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hammer.js does a pretty good job on detecting whether it is running on a multitouch enabled system or not.

In most cases it also works pretty well when you have both, a mouse and a touch display. We are developing a desktop web-application based on hammer.js, which should work both, with mouse and multitouch interaction and it mostly works fine. However, it seems that this scenario is not as well tested as the use on mobile devices. See for example this open bug, when hammer.js triggers a tap event twice on Chrome (https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/302) which got closed in between, because no activity was detected.

Note also, that it is often needed to fine tune the behaviour of hammer.js, by fiddling with the user_select, user_drag and prevent_default parameters (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271523/hammer-js-behaviour-of-userselect-for-nested-html-elements) ). On Google Chrome we also had to enable the experimental touch-actions : none. I do not know, how much of this is specific to desktop systems though.

**Summary**
Hammer.js is written with desktop systems in mind and does quite a good job in providing sensible behaviour on both mouse and touch based systems. In detail it requires sometime fine tuning to make everything work as expected.